# how to retrive data from parse.com and store in spinner

Tags: android, parse-platform, spinner

this is how i did .
use adapter to store data first and then attach it to spinner
define `djtry().execute()` in **oncreate** .

```
private class DjTry extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(CreateClasstalk.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Parse.com Simple ListView Tutorial");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                "Country");
        query.orderByAscending("country_name");
        try {
            ob = query.find();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
 //       listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // Pass the results into an ArrayAdapter
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CreateClasstalk.this,
                R.layout.example_item);
        // Retrieve object countrt_name from Parse.com database
        for (ParseObject country : ob) {
            adapter.add((String) country.get("country_name"));

            Log.d("DJ ADAPTER",country.toString());
        }

        country.setAdapter(adapter);





        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
```

And why not You are returning ob from doInBackground(), that way you will receive ob in onPostExecute(Object ob)